# Resharper 6.0 tab instead of spaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

How to force resharper 6.0 to use tab instead of spaces during code clearup ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in ReSharper. It typically uses the VS settings, but when aligning it always uses spaces and ignores the VS settings (particularly the Smart Tabs).

A request for a fix to this has been around since version 4, but is still not fixed in verstion 6 (the most recent release).

The bug is noted here: [RSRP-150306](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-150306)
and here: [RSRP-200204](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-200204)

Update: One thing you can do to work around this issue, after doing the ReSharper cleanup, you can use the VS formatting call to have it fix the tabs/spaces. The default shortcut for this is

- Ctrl-K,Ctrl-D for the entire document
- Ctrl-K,Ctrl-F for just the selected text.

Answer (score 12):

ReSharper uses VS settings, it doesn't have own settings for this task.
Go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->Necessary lang or All Languages->Tabs and select "Insert spaces" or "Keep tabs".

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to install the Productivity Power Tools package (through NuGet or [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)) and then enable the 'Fix Mixed Tabs' option which offers you an option to Tabify or Spaceify files when it senses a mixture.